# Regex to match link text & url in list

Tags: regex, vb.net

I got an html list as String, in which every element contains exactly one link.

I want to extract the Url and the Text of the links

### The List:

```
<ul id="list-id">
    <li><a href="match this">match this too</a></li>
    <li><a href="match this">match this too</a></li>
    <li><a href="match this">match this too</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the Regex that i got which matches only the last link:

```
/<ul id=['"]list-id['"]>\s*(?:<li><a href=['"]([^'"]+)['"]>([^<]+)<\/a><\/li>\s*)*<\/ul>/i
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zW0jR1/3)

Comment: You can try this one :  https://regex101.com/r/zW0jR1/5

Answer (score 0):

You can capturing both url and name it can be reuse with $1, $2 ...

https://regex101.com/r/zW0jR1/4

New Regex `.+href="(.+)">(.+)<`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `/<li><a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a><\/li>/`

Then you can run the `scan` method.

```
string = '<ul id="list-id">
           <li><a href="match this">match this too</a></li>
           <li><a href="match this">match this too</a></li>
           <li><a href="match this">match this too</a></li>
         </ul>'

string.scan(/<li><a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a><\/li>/)
```

This would return a 2d array

```
[["match this", "match this too"], 
 ["match this", "match this too"], 
 ["match this", "match this too"]]
```

Comment: but if there is another list with an different id it would match it too